# What is the consensus about what is a signal?

Tags: terminology

I know that "what is a signal?" is a matter of opinion, but I hope to find out about a consensus.

Is for example, by consensus, a signal is:

- A sampled wave
- A sampled mass
- A sampled energy (both waves and masses)
- Sampled energy as an emergent phenomenon

Comment: The sensibility of your question's physical aspect hasn't improved since your last question. It also still has no correct answer. We study signals. The comments to your previous question defined that quite nicely and you're not picking up any of the things you've learned there. So, this seems to be a duplicate of your already-closed https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/76682/are-signals-of-matter-studied-under-signal-processing .

Comment: @mmmm Of course you meant my last question here, not anywhere else; that said, I find your comment cynical. I am sure that there is reasonable consensus within SP in regards to if signal's source is generally a wave or generally a mass. I find.

Comment: Also, @mmmm you are wrong, I understood very well that as a principle SP researchers study "signals" and that's it; I am interested to know if there is a consensus. Since my last question is about to be automatically deleted, I tried to ask a better question, sorry if it didn't went well; this sort of thing happens you know.

Comment: I tried to edit the question; sometimes asking the right question can be very hard.

Comment: Well a consensus was shown in the comments to the linked question: a signal is a quantity changing along a scalar axis (or multiple of these). There are more restrictive definitions for scientific sub-fields, but it's really not clear where you intended to take this.

Comment: @signalmodeler A signal isn't a distinct "physical thing" like a particle with charge, it's an _emergent property_ of things. If we can measure it, it's a signal. I tried to provide an intuition but the question's become even broader since -- I suggest asking on philosophy SE if this is unsatisfactory, or reading up on overviews of SP.

Comment: @mmmm I didn't grasp it as a "consensus", I actually asked what is a `scalar axis (or multiple of these)` this morning in another website, as it may help me understand that definition. I only take this to get an answer (not a comment) about what is the consensus.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I guess you say it's an emergence because it's at least two physical things and not just one (as must be at least for discrete / two state) signal, right?

Comment: @mmmm I didn't understand some of the things I read there by the way, I might currently lack some physics and philosophy knowledge to do so, let along English is not my native language.

Comment: @signalmodeler No; a single electron, if we measure it, is a signal - since we can quantify it as a process (e.g. its momentum, frequency over time). Nevermind "emergent property", it's complicated (and not strictly relevant).

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon please don't give over me so fast, it's not complicated for me, I can understand where you take this --- the photon, the lab, the man doing the sampling, they are all together an emergence (or at least some of them are in the mind of the researcher); if by consensus a signal is *an emergent phenomenon* that should be a base for a new answer, I guess.

Comment: I say "it's complicated" since it's good intuition for the marcoscopic but fails for individual particles. There are also "fundamental properties" like charge, and these are also signals. This question's not something I'm willing to write about here, but I'll grant you, it's not a "matter of opinion" - it can be answered objectively and definitively.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon please plea for deleting the entire comment section because I can't do it myself as a non registered user. Since my vast edits to the question these comments are no longer relevant and bias interpreting my question (which also got one upvote !).

Comment: @signalmodeler I'd say the exact opposite: your question is even more vague without knowing the discussion behind it.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I what? The question itself is very clear "is there a consensus and if so what is it"? A "discussion" is just unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

Within the field of signal processing (the "SP" in "DSP") a signal is a mathematical abstraction for a scalar or vector quantity that evolves over some other scaler (or sometimes vector) domain.

Strictly speaking, signals are dimensionless (pure mathematical abstraction, remember), although they can be *carried* on some physical quantity, such as voltage, velocity, horse turds per second, or whatever makes sense to solve the problem at hand.

Usually, signals evolve over time, but in the field of image processing an image can be considered to be a "signal" that evolves over the domain of the 2D space of an image (and then further over the time dimension, if one is processing video).

Signals can have a continuous domain (i.e., $x(t)$, where $t$ is a real number), or they can have a discrete domain (i.e., $x_n,\ n \in \mathcal I$).  Discrete-domain signals can be generated by sampling a continuous-domain signal (i.e., $x_t = x(n T_s)$).  But since $x(t)$ isn't necessarily a *wave*, nor is it necessary to generate a discrete signal by sampling, it is restrictive to say a signal is a "sampled wave".  Or sampled-mass, or sampled-energy, or sampled horse turds.

Just accept the fact that *for the purposes of doing signal processing* the first thing that you have to do is accept that you're taking a trip into mathemagic land.  Part of your job, if you're working with something real (like trying to deal with how the amount of mass in a tank evolves over time) that you will *first* take the problem and abstract it into math, then you will *solve* the problem in math, then you will finally have to *make sense* of the math in terms of your real world.

Comment: I disagree with embedding "evolving" into the definition, implying a signal is necessarily a process and not a state. An image captures a temporal slice of physical dimensionality, there's no "evolving" any more than an apple evolves into an orange in a fruits image. There are SP methods built explicitly with this distinction in mind.

Comment: A still image still evolves over the x and y dimension.  Even a still image that's all neutral gray is, technically, evolving -- it's just the evolution is very, very boring.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon I strictly and fully disagree with you. Without variability over some dimension, it's a state, not a signal. As Tim says, that variability might not manifest in actual differing values. But a single value is not a signal. E.g. $5$ is not a signal, $f(t) = 5$ is one.

Comment: It _varies_ over x and y; "evolving" is more appropriate for the _same_ feature that changes w.r.t. another in a causal or sequential manner, such as individual pixels in a video or sensors in EEG. Adjacent pixels are related only spatially.

Comment: @MarcusMüller variability != evolution. It's mostly terminology at this point, but worth distinguishing. However, you stated "a state is not a signal" -- an image is a state, not a process.

Comment: @OverLordGoldDragon again, an image is a signal *because* it can vary along its axes. That's the point. An image is a function $f[n,m]$ of pixel coordinates.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I already agreed variability is a fair criterion. Axes are merely a generalization of a single channel and aren't pertinent to the definition; if anything they are incorrectly restrictive, as some SP methods are dedicated to data which cannot be organized into a tensor.

Answer (score 0):

This question is very broad (if not ill-defined) and subject to a long article, or a book - but I'll take a shot.

In broadest sense, a "signal" is anything which can be *observed* and *quantified*. This includes an individual *state*, and a *process* - i.e. *continuum of states*. Put differently, a signal is anything that science can study.

An image is a signal. A radio wave is a signal. One is a *state*, i.e. process fixed in time, other is a process, i.e. continuum of states.

While nearly anything can be a signal, not everything is subject to *signal processing*. Signal processing, broadly speaking, tasks itself with *manipulating the information within a state or process* for some goal, such as transmission, storage, analysis. This contrasts with e.g. physics, which seeks to explain the underlying causality of physical systems.

> would it be correct to say that signal processing researchers research only "wave signals" but not "mass signals"?

A "mass signal" would qualify as a "state". Scans of minerals or human anatomy, which are "masses", are fair game for SP.

This answer simplifies in a few regards and should be interpreted loosely. Consider also asking on [Philosophy.SE](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/), if this is a general intellectual inquiry. Else, narrow the question to your exact goal.